# Call a new form from current form in c#

Tags: c#, forms

I want to create a program which have the same theme and looks like new forms are loading inside the current form from c#. I can do this by using panels but I do not wish to do so since if I had to do a modification it becomes a cumbersome.Instead of using panels I used forms. when i click a button in a form same style form with different values will appear on the current form. But it's looking so untidy and when i want to close the program I have to close every form. Since my final program will contain more than 15 guis it is not a practicle solution .so tried by using following code snippet.

```
 private void ord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            order frm =new order();
            frm.Show();

        }
```

From this code I suppose to close the current form and display the next form. But this code didn't work .It closed both forms.

I can use `this.hide()` method instead of `this.close` .but its only hide the current form.When I want to close the Program I have to close each and every form.

I don't wish to use MDI forms. Because it is not suit for my theme. you can get idea about my theme by looking at following image.

[GUI of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaLeW.png)

And I want to design a professional looking GUI. I also like to have comments about my GUI. Is it looking professional?

Comment: You don't need to keep track of the opened forms. All opened application forms are kept in the [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection. It is not very difficult to loop over this collection and close everything.

Comment: The problem is that when you close your "MainForm" (i.e. the one that you specified in `Application.Run`), the application quits. You can search SO/Internet how to avoid that, but in general it would be much easier for you if you keep your UI with a single form, and design the other "forms" as `UserControl`s.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
private void ord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                order frm =new order();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
```

if its still not working ?
then probably you are using forms in parent child fashion if you close the form which is running at the very start all the forms will be closed, **Solution**: you should hide child form  using .Hide() and for the next form to open declare the parent form as mdi parent of child form hope you understand...